# HTML button Redirect to file in parent directory

Tags: html, forms, button

Currently, the button on my site does nothing on click. I would like it to redirect to ../requests

```html
<form method="get" action="../requests">
    <input class ="button" type="button" name="prev_next" value="Request Item">
</form>
```

I have trouble understanding what's happening here. So, I have a form and the method is get, which will get me a URL. Then, I have the action so that it can go to ../requests, the file in my local directory.

Inside of it I have a button that says "Request Item" on it. Where is this going wrong?

Comment: `type='submit'`

Comment: Change the input to a button and set its type as "submit"

Comment: If you are wanting a simple redirect try this: `<button onclick="location.href = '../requests';">Request Item</button>`

Comment: @Hudson it works, but how do I keep the css that was applied to all the prev_next names?

Comment: set the name attribute in that button. It doesn't have to be in a form, unless you forced the CSS rule to form > button

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<input>` `type` to `submit` like this:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="prev_next" value="Request Item">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your button to a submit type instead of a button type for forms.

`<input type="submit" class="button" />`

Just to point out, ../request doesn't seem to be a file?

Comment: Maybe that's my issue? So if it is outside of my directory, how do I correctly access it?

Comment: You're issue is definitely that you didn't have your input type as a submit, that's why it wasn't redirecting you. If it's not finding you're file then that is a different issue. If after you change your input to type="submit" and that doesn't work,  would you mind editing your post to include your file directory I.E. 
Folder/
--index.html
  -- Files
Folder2/
--Filetofind.txt